# DNN redirect Loop

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am trying to duplicate an existing DNN portal that I have for testing purposes by creating a duplicate of the database and duplicating the .net files into a new folder.

After I copied the site and changed the webconfig to point to the new site and changed the alias in the database I am getting this error.

---

This webpage has a redirect loop.

The webpage at http://xxx.us/xxx/default.aspx has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.

Comment: JAllen, did you solve this problem? If Mike's answer helped, please mark it accepted.

Comment: Any solutions? please share!

Answer (score 4):

Here's a list of [common causes](http://jw0rd.net/2009/05/09/dotnetnuke-redirect-loop/) for DNN redirect loops:

> 1) You are setting the trust level to
>   medium and using the 1.0.61025.0
>   version of System.Web.Extensions.
>   Update the trust level to full and and
>   update ALL occurrences of
>   System.Web.Extensions to 3.5.0.0 in
>   the web.config (assuming .NET 3.5
>   framework is installed).
>
> Original:

```
<trust level="Medium"... ...
 ...System.Web.Extensions,
 Version=1.0.61025.0...
```

> Updated:

```
 <trust level="Full"... ...
 ...System.Web.Extensions,
 Version=3.5.0.0...
```

You should also check if there is a System.Web.Extensions.dll (version 1.0.61025.0) in the /bin directory. If no compiled module is dependent on this assembly version, you can remove the file. Otherwise, use assembly redirection in the web.config runtime section:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

> 2) You have a trailing slash in the
>   HTTPAlias field in the PortAlias
>   table, remove it.

Answer (score 1):

JAllen, in my experience, this is an incorrectly formatted PortalAlias record.

My suggestion is to try a few extra iterations.

Examples:

- "localhost" works for me, but "localhost/" does not.
- "www.domain.com" works, but "domain.com" does not. (because domain.com is not bound in IIS, whereas www.domain.com is"

The specific value that goes into your PortalAlias table depends upon your IIS bindings. You may also need to check your hosts file to verify that localhost is available to you

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

In over 20 DNN deployments, this has caused me some pain a handful of times, at least.

Comment: In my case I had to set the PortalID to 0 it was initially at 1 after comparing with another DNN Site that was working and had to recycle the App Pool for the site before it worked

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this issue for a solid day and I can add an item to the list of common causes:

> Cannot communicate with SQL Server

After disabling TLS1.0 and SSLv3 for a PCI compliance scan, we started getting the error: `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.  I could ping the server and could login to the server(from SSMS on the database server), but when I tried making an ODBC connection from the web server to the database, it failed.

It would try to hit the home page (and fail), then continuously tried to redirect to the UnderConstruction page, failing each time until we got the error.

I had to re-enable TLS1.0 to get it working, but definitely a short term fix.