# how to solve "The page isn't redirecting properly" error in dotnetnuke

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, dotnetnuke

i install dnn 6.2, firefox show error meesage "The page isn't redirecting properly" when i want access to site by this url: www.mydomain.com. 
i only access to site by this url: www.mydomain.com/default.aspx
how to solve this error

Comment: Duplicate of [DNN redirect Loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040121/dnn-redirect-loop). Please use the search. :)

Comment: i see that, but not solve my problem

Comment: Then you might want to explain in some more detail how your redirect is set up and whether it only occurred after updating an existing DotNetNuke installation, or also on a clean install.

Comment: My guess is that the true question is http://www.mydomain.com doesn't work.  Yet http://www.mydomain.com/default.aspx does work.  If this is the case, you might edit to clarify to keep grumpy people happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most commonly with older versions of DotNetNuke this is due to the portal alias value having a / at the end of it.  verify in the PortalAlias table that there isn't a / at the end.

Otherwise, it is due to not having a wild-card mapping that is setup for IIS.